# using backbone router with Aura

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, aura.js

Trying to build a web client application with backbone aura. Struggling to add router to the application. did anyone try adding router to backbone aura yet?

Comment: I feel there is a great need for a good example of this. What did you end up with? I currently made an extension that makes the router on `afterAppStart`

Comment: How did you make this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Backbone router, but I built a simple router that listens to every message each component send and update the URL, and listens for every change in URL and sends specific messages. As an extension I couldn't make it work (because it would render before the components that needed to listen for its messages -- at least the first based on the initial URL), so I built it as a component.